# How do I could transfer a software from OneDrive folder in my Host to my VM terminal of Ubuntu server 20.04 and then install it?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, transfer

The scenario I have is: I am using Workstation 10 and my laptop, and running a virtual machine Ubuntu server 20.04 I have my terminal open, I am using Windows 10 pro as host and on my desktop I have the OneDrive folder, both are configured with brigde Network connection and they can ping each other, what I need is from the terminal of my Ubuntu server virtual machine to transfer that software that is in my Host's Desktop (Windows 10) and then install it using the terminal, what would be the commands that allow me run this task? As software you can give me an example and give me the steps how to do it.

Comment: There's also the VM shared folder option, but without saying which virtualization software you're using, no way to help there

Comment: Vmware Workstation 10 The scenario I have is: I am using Workstation 10 and my laptop....